# Redundant Data Members

Tags: c++, datamember

I have a class A which stores a SquareMatrix.

```
class A{
private:
    SquareMatrix mat;
};
```

The class frequently uses the size of the matrix using mat.size() (a constant time operation). mat.size() really is another measure of the size of A. Following good coding practice, should A also store a copy of mat.size()?

```
class A{
private:
    SquareMatrix mat;
    int size;
};
```

Comment: I personally don't see any benefit to add this, given this small and incomplete example. Do you see any benefit of doing so in your codebase? Would you still add it after seeing that presence or absence of benefit?

Comment: "Good coding practice"?  Maybe you mean creating an accessor/property method to mat's size, e.g. `int GetSize() const {return mat.size();}`, but that only assumes A's GetSize() means the size of private mat.  GetMatSize() might be a better name if GetSize() is ambiguous.

Comment: There is another question (besides `should I`) - CAN YOU? I mean, can the size of `SquareMatrix` change without you being notified? This issue is similar to cache invalidation. Also, if that `SquareMatrix` stores its size (don't need to recalculate it every time), I'd rather get it whenever needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Storing a *data member* that represents the size of `A` in this example is not a good idea if *"mat.size() really is another measure of the size of A"*.

The primary issue here is: how is `A::size` supposed to keep track of changes to `SquareMatrix::size()`? This value can change in potentially many places, and keeping them both in sync will be tricky, and difficult to maintain even if you pull that off.

Instead, provide a *member function* for `A` that simply returns the result of `mat.size()` like this:

```
class A{
  private:
    SquareMatrix mat;
  public:    
    int size() const { return mat.size(); }  // mat.size() IS A's size :)
};
```